# Radeon Graphics error after Upgrade

Tags: 16.04

I have upgraded ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04

After upgrade it starts giving error about Radeon graphic card

```
radeon vce init error (-22)
```

on start up.

Any fixes please?

I have run the command

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output is as follows

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
Subsystem: Lenovo Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 The output of  `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' `  is as follows  `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
 Kernel driver in use: i915`

Comment: I do not see any radeon adapter. Please run this `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'`

Comment: @Pilot6 Output of above command is  `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)
 Kernel driver in use: radeon
 Kernel modules: radeon
`